# Issue with java8 lambda expression and foreach

Tags: java, lambda

I have a list like below

```
List<String> fruits = new ArrayList<>();
fruits.add("apple");
fruits.add("mango");
fruits.add("grapes");
System.out.println(fruits.toString());
```

I am using lambda expression for printing the list like

```
fruits.forEach(item->System.out.println(item));
```

and its working fine my requirement is I need to iterate over the list and concatenate the items to a string

```
String stringFruits = "";
fruits.forEach(item->stringFruits = stringFruits+item);
```

this is giving a compile time error saying **variable values used in lambda should be effectively final** is there any way I can do it in java 8 ?

Comment: `String stringFruits = fruits.stream().collect(Collectors.joining());`

Comment: @Eran thanks it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don’t need to do that by hand at all. If your source is a `List`, you can just use

```
String stringFruits = String.join(", ", fruits);
System.out.println(stringFruits);
```

The first argument to [`String.join(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-) is the delimiter.

Answer (score 7):

You need to `join` via a `delimiter`. In this case the delimiter is going to be `,`; but you can choose any you want.

```
 String result = fruits.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
 System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Big gun for a small problem. In that case, there’s the convenient simple method [`String.join(…)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43784884/2711488)…

Answer (score 4):

Java8 introduced a **StringJoiner** that does what you need (is another alternative to erans comment)

```
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner("-,-");
fruits.forEach(item -> sj.add(item));
```

here the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html)

edit:

for the posterity you can do as well:

```
String result = fruits.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
System.out.println(result);
```

or

```
String stringFruits = String.join(", ", fruits);
System.out.println(stringFruits);
```

credits and thanks to  @Holger

Comment: And since this is so practical, there’s [`String.join(…)` already doing that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43784884/2711488)…

Answer (score 1):

Or a pre-Java8 solution:

```
String combined = "";
for (String s : fruits) {
   combined += s;
}
```

... and one with delimiter:

```
String combined = "";
for (String s : fruits) {
   combined = combined + ", " + s;
}
```

Comment: It's usually best to use a `StringBuilder` when you're looping. Concatentation gets exponentially slower in a loop.